# Sqlite Database multi threaded SELECT and UPDATE operation confusion

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am creating a mufti threaded application that uses a Sqlite database to store information.

One of the thread performs a SELECT operation where it selects rows where a particular column is blank as follows:

```
for i in cursor.execute('SELECT Beeid from SongLink WHERE Dlink=\'\''):
```

THe other thread also accesses the database and tries to change the **Dlink value** of the columns.

Will the above code always give the columns where **Dlink=\'\''** taking care of the updates made by the other thread or this could lead to wrong row selections

Comment: Out of curiosity, why query for `\'\'` when `""` would do, and why not use `NULL`s?

Comment: It's just a old habit to escape all kinds of quotes but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [separate connections per thread](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), and SQLite will maintain data integrity.

Changes to the database in one connection are not going to be visible in other threads until you a) commit the changes and b) a new transaction is started in the connections that want to see that new data.

You do want to set the `check_same_thread` parameter of the connection to `True`.

Comment: Thanks.However say I commit the changes in the second thread that changes the Dlink value.The Select command from the first thread then might also show values that  doesn't have Dlink as "". Please enlighten.

Comment: @SteveIrwin: not until you start a new transaction, it won't. And the database won't ever return values that don't match your query.